# rack::proxy does not work to specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Got stuck not sure what is happening.

If I do not specify path and run perform request it works fine.

```
def perform_request(env)
  env["HTTP_HOST"] = "node:8765"
  super(env)
end
```

However when I want to proxy if match some path it does not work.

```
def perform_request(env)
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  if request.path =~ %r{^/api/check}
    #puts "Weird!!!!!"
    env["HTTP_HOST"] = "node:8765"
    super(env)
  else
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Configured as middleware(config/application.rb):

```
config.middleware.use NProxy, {ssl_verify_none: true}
```

Comment: Just in case, try another way of changing HTTP_HOST as in the following article - http://livsey.org/blog/2012/02/23/using-rack-proxy-to-serve-multiple-rails-apps-from-the-same-domain-and-port/. Also, pls elaborate on what means "does not work" here - what exactly happens. Did you try other checks then path matching, e.g. if true, etc.

Comment: "does not work" - I get respond back - "404 not found".  I tried to rewrite_env too.  No, I did not check path other ways.